# Black dots in render with many lamps

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

Hi fellas any help with the black dots on the render below? Found some info around the web but nothing helped me out (it was an old stuff in fact). Really dunno what could causing this...

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4980/599

Comment: Hi Gandalf I know about this topic and already saw it but its something different cause I found out that the render getting worse with more lights **despite they could not be seen** (are behind walls in different rooms) so Im wondering why this is happening.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30407/599

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default cycles samples one lamp at a time. The black spots likely correspond to samples where cycles was attempting to sample lights which are doing nothing for actually illuminating the visible objects.

You could try disabling [Multiple Importance Sampling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5309/599) on lamps/materials you know won't contribute much to illuminating the scene, and/or play with the *Light Sampling Threshold* in *Properties > Render settings > Sampling*.

However, if that doesn't cut it, then you can use the *Branched Path Integrator*, which allows for sampling all lights at once:

[image: *found in Properties > Render settings > Sampling*]

Note that it works a bit differently from the default integrator, so try playing around with [the settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html#branched-path-tracing) to see what works.

Comment: THX mate already found out that BPT makes a better results but still try to "fiddling" it up. Light sampling threshold already tried but makes not much of a difference in my tests. Btw sampling one lamp at a time sounds "weird" somehow ... how its working in fact?

Comment: Looks like its very useful in areas with even low light but in areas where is almost black (really dark) this BPT method is noisy as hell.

Comment: @JanMatys I'm not too sure of the specifics beyond what brecht (the original author of cycles) said here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23006/599. As for noise in really dark areas, you could try playing with *sample all indirect lights*. Whether it hurts or helps rather depends.

Comment: Playing? This could be turned on or off or ... am I missing something buddy?

Comment: @JanMatys I mean making test renders with it on and off and observing the effects on noise/render time.